# Apps script to copy hyperlink to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, copy-paste

I'm new to javascript and need to copy 3 colums of a google spreadsheet to a second sheet (one column has hyperlink url value).

My main sheet "Responses" creates a new row of data when a website booking form is submitted. I need to copy the last row entry to the next sheet, "Sheet1".

The first sheet "Responses" should copy the last row, column K, M and column V (a website hyperlink).
Pasted values should go in the next available row of "Sheet1" column A, B and C respectively, with the active hyperlinks in column C of "Sheet1".

I'm looking for javascript for google apps script, so I can put it on a macro/trigger, to copy the new entry to the next sheet automatically.

Can anybody help with the script please?

Comment: Hi. Everyone is _new_ to apps script at some stage. The process that you describe is VERY basic. I respectfully suggest that you begin by learning how to `extend Google Sheets` and specifically [how to read and write data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started).

Answer (score 0):

To get you started in using Google App Script with Spreadsheet, here is an example script that will do what you want.  As a habit I always wrap my code in try {} catch {} block so when my project gets big I can tell where the error occured.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Responses");
    // get all the values from the last row of Response.
    // in getRange() rows and columns start with 1.  column A is 1
    let values = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    // for arrays the index starts with 0 so column K is 10
    let result = [values[0][10],values[0][12]];
    // hyperlinks are in Rich Text format, again V is column 22
    let hyper = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),22).getRichTextValue();
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
    sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,result.length).setValues([result]);
    sheet.getRange(lastRow,3).setRichTextValue(hyper);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range.getRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue)
- [Range.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow)
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Range.setRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue)
- [javascript Array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

Comment: Legend! That's pretty much exactly what I need, thank you. Only thing is, it's overwriting the same row in sheet1 and not putting it in the next available row.

Comment: Sorry should be lastRow+1

Comment: Yeh that's adding it to the next available row, but the values are not copying over correctly now. In sheet1 colum A shows value "0" (should show an email address), column B value "1150" (should show street address) and column B is empty (should be a hyperlink).

Comment: You said it worked but put on the wrong line.  Sorry about that it was my mistake.  Now you say the values are not copying correctly.  Are cell K and M simple string values or formatted somehow?  If so you could use `getRichTextValues()` instead of `getValues()`

Comment: Yes, your first response was copying data to sheet1 (but not the next empty row)... I used the edited script and it sends weird data to sheet1 and no link in last column. First two colums are just text and the third should be a hyperlink

Comment: Do you have a solution to get this working properly? I can't figure out why it's not working

Comment: My solution should work.  You said it did and then it didnt.   Without having you data available there is realy nothing more I can do.  Check the integrity of your data.  Or post your latest code and I can see if you missed something.